# Squeak - SUnit Testing for Errors

Tags: squeak

I have been suggested to use should:rise in my test case to test for errors that a method might raise. For some reason it does not work as expected, so I want to verify that I'm doing it right. Here is the code in the test case:

```
self should: [aMyClass compareTo: 'This is a string'] raise: 'invalid input'.
```

My compareTo/1 method looks like this:

```
(aMyClass isKindOf: MyClass) ifFalse: [self error: 'invalid input'.].
```

The test runner output is that there is "1 errors".

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#should:raise:` expects an Exception class as its second argument, similar to the first argument of `#on:do:` in exception handling:

```
 self should: [ aMyClass compareTo: 'This is a string' ] raise: Error
```

Comment: How can I distinguish between different errors the compareTo might raise?
I have just started learning squeak, so I am not yet familiar with error/exception mechanism.

Comment: To differentiate the errors nest the handlers: `[ [ aMyClass compareTo: 'This is a string' ] on: ErrorType1 do: [ :err | ... ] ] on: ErrorType2 do: [ :err | ... ]`. Check out the Pharo by Example 2 (http://www.pharobyexample.org/) draft chapter on exceptions: https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/26600/PBE2-Exceptions-2010-03-02.pdf.